# How to grep recursively and ignore subdirectories of subdirectories?

Tags: linux, macos, recursion, grep

I am already familiar with `grep -r "searchTerm" .` and I am familiar with `grep -r "searchTerm" exclude={subdir1, subdir2} .` However, I am looking for a way to grep recursively, through subdirectories and ignore certain subdirectories of subdirectories.

For example, if the directory structure is as follows:

```
/folder
   /subdir1
      /idc/file.js
      /files/file.js
      /otherStuffIdc/file.js
   /subdir2
      /idc/file2.js
      /files/file2.js
      /otherStuffIdc/file2.js
...
```

How would I be able to exclude idc and otherStuffIdc, since these folders are subdirectories of subdirectories of the root directory I am beginning my search in?

My example is simplified but in my real world issue, there are many, many `subDir#` so it is not feasible for me to just grep each individual subdirectory.

Comment: Do you want to exclude `idc` and all its subdirectories from the search ?

Comment: Yes! Precisely. I want to exclude `idc` and `otherStuffIdc`

Comment: `grep -r pattern --exclude-dir=idc`, this didn't work ?

Comment: This does work, I must have been messing this up earlier. Thanks @iamauser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will exclude the (sub)directories with names `idc` and `otherStuffIdc`.

```
 grep -r pattern --exclude-dir=idc,otherStuffIdc
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, this worked only with curly braces around the (sub)folders

```
grep -r pattern --exclude-dir={idc,otherStuffIdc}
```

Comment: On what OS is that?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04. : )

Comment: I just tried again without the curly braces and it didn't work.. weird